# .NET Soap Service: Hide Methods without Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

we have a WebAPI for several customers. It is build on a SOAP service.

We sell several parts of this API, so that every customer can decide what he wants and what he needs.

Question is: Is it possible to show the methods only for authenticated users, respectively only show the methods he has paid for?

Comment: When you say, "show the methods", do you mean to show them on the help page?

Comment: Also, do you mean WCF services, or legacy ASMX services?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can selectively expose certain methods based on a user.

A different approach may be to add a security key as a parameter to each of the methods that would be unique to your authenticated users. You could use this key to determine if they are authenticated, or have paid, to use that method.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea. I would disable autogenerated WSDL on the web service side. Then I would generate the WSDL with the contacts that are suitable for respective client and provide this manualy generated WSDL to the clients by sharing it, for instance, through the web or sending via email or... the client can generate their proxies based on the wsdl that they have and other methods will be invisible for them.

Answer (score 1):

If there are a manageable number of operations and different configurations then the nice way would be to have different endpoints on the service which expose the `ServiceOperations`. Users could then opt (to buy) one of the different endpoints, gaining access to the different operations.

e.g.

```
// the implementation
public class OurService : PackageA, PackageB
{        
    public void OperationA() //
    public int OperationB() //
    public string AnotherOperation() //
}

// the endpoints:
public interface PackageA
{
    void OperationA();
    string AnotherOperation();
}

public interface PackageB
{
    void OperationB();
    string AnotherOperation();
}
```

You could potentially make an interface for each client as they choose the operations they want. Each interface / endpoint can have its own security model and address.

The less nice way is to make a more generic service. The service would need to accept an basic object and an instruction to describe the operation. The service determines who the user is, checks whether they are allowed to use that operation, and either aborts or proceeds.

In this case there's no visibility of how the service runs, and the user would only know about the potential 'operations' based on the documentation you provide.